# What is an expression like `[variable_name]` called and how is it used?

Tags: python, syntax

I have been working through a [tutorial](https://github.com/tsoding/kdtree-in-python) and encountered unfamiliar Python syntax. Looking to identify what it's called and learn how it works.

**Mystery Code**

The [line(s) in question](https://github.com/tsoding/kdtree-in-python/blob/d4c4d2a15693b73ab5c3feeaf25bda75174faa5f/main.py#L162) involve a variable name surrounded by square braces before being set:

```
[pivot] = get_point_by_id(svg_tree, 'pivot')
```

**Relevant Clue to Posted Answers**

My initial thought was that it had something to do with being set to a list since the return value from [get_point_by_id](https://github.com/tsoding/kdtree-in-python/blob/d4c4d2a15693b73ab5c3feeaf25bda75174faa5f/main.py#L28) is a list.

Untouched, the code runs fine. But if I try to recreate the syntax like this:

```
[variable_name] = [1,2,3]
print(variable_name)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

Comment: pack/unpack is the term you're missing -- as it says in the error message.  We can't comment on your confusion, as your examples fall short of being a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll take a guess from your posting: in your first example, `pivot` is a list that happens to be of the same shape as the functional return.  In contrast, `variable_name` in the second value is *not* a sequence of three scalars.

The list represents a sequence of values; you can assign the sequence to a matching sequence of variables.  For instance:

```
>>> [a, b] = [2, 3]
>>> a
2
>>> b
3
```

we usually write this without brackets, simply

```
a, b = [2, 3]
```

Comment: A guess is more than enough. You're correct - both lists are three elements long. Thanks for highlighting the 'packing/unpacking' terminology too.

Answer (score 1):

The *left-hand-side* of the assignment is the target list.

From [7.2. Assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

> Assignment of an object to a target list, optionally enclosed in
>   parentheses or square brackets, is recursively defined as follows.
>
> - If the target list is a single target with no trailing comma,
>     optionally in parentheses, the object is assigned to that target.
> - Else: The object must be an iterable with the **same number of items as
>     there are targets** in the target list, and the items are assigned, from
>     left to right, to the corresponding targets.

The following works because the number of items in the target list is the same as the in the object on the *right-hand-side* of the assignment.

```
In [17]: [a] = ['foo']

In [18]: a
Out[18]: 'foo'
```

In your mystery code, `get_point_by_id` must return an iterable with one item.